# c++ string manipulation to android studio java

Tags: java, android, c++

All

I would like to ask help regarding how to achieve this on android java.
Basically, I have to convert this line of codes from **C++** to **java**

```
char cnt[6][4];
char total[6][13];
char batch_totals[91];

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    strcpy(cnt[i], "000");
    strcpy(total[i], "000000000000");
}
sprintf(cnt[0], "%03d", apple_sale_count);
sprintf(cnt[1], "%03d", mango_sale_count);
sprintf(cnt[3], "%03d", grapes_sale_count);
sprintf(total[0], "%012d", apple_sale_total);
sprintf(total[1], "%012d", mango_sale_total);
sprintf(total[3], "%012d", grapes_sale_total);
memset(batch_totals, 0x00, sizeof(batch_totals));

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    strcat(batch_totals, cnt[i]);
    strcat(batch_totals, total[i]);
}
```

basically it should look like this once printed on logs in android java:

Without values:

> 000 000000000000 000 000000000000 000 000000000000 000 000000000000 000 000000000000 000 000000000000 000 000000000000

With sample values:

> 032 000002400000 020 000003200100 000 000000000000 052 000006710000 000 000000000000 000 000000000000 000 000000000000

take note that I just indicated the spaces so that it can easily be understood

thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? What're the inputs?

Comment: not yet. i'm still learning java, the inputs are char and int